# Add new local directory to a git remote branch

Tags: git

I have a directory on my PC I'd like to add to a particular branch in a remote git repo on my server. I have git, the branch was created fresh off the master from the server, but I've got an entire project with which I would like to use git.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Clone the remote repository on to your PC.

`git clone user@example.com:myproject.git`

Checkout the branch to which you would like to add those files.

`cd myproject`

`git checkout -b my_new_branch`

Move the files into your project directory, then add & commit them.

`git add .`

`git commit -m "new files for my new branch"`

You'll probably want to push, too.

`git push origin my_new_branch`